# Calling async function and wait for results in an element class in Vue 3

Tags: image, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs3, aspect-ratio

> I am using Vue 3 and  Composition API

I am trying to apply a class to a div depending on a function's results but the code is not working. The class is being applied even before the function is completed.

Here is the code:

```
<div
  v-for="(image, index) in gallery.images"
  :key="index"
  :class="{ 'wide': isWide(image.thumb) }">
     <img
     @click="openLightbox(image.thumb)"
     :src="image.thumb"
     :alt="'image ' + (index + 1)"/>
</div>
```

This is the Vue function being called:

```
    const isWide = async (imageUrl) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const img = new Image();

        img.onload = () => {
          const aspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
          resolve(aspectRatio >= 1.5);
        };

        img.src = imageUrl;
      });
    };
```

---

How do I fix this?

I am expecting to apply the `wide` class if the aspect ratio (width/height) is greater than or equal to `1.5`.

Comment: `return new Promise` returns a value that is truthy.  You would be better off not binding an async function call to a class.  Bind some simple reactive variable that receives the result of the async function and is only ever true or false.

Comment: It doesn't work this way, you need to form an array of ready to use images with relevant data before outputting them in a template